# JavaFX Drag Node / Object to Windows Desktop

Tags: windows, macos, javafx, drag-and-drop

I'm using JavaFX's Drag&Drop in my application, and it has been working well for MacOS-X but not for Windows.

The goal is: When dragging the TabGraphic to the OS Desktop I want to create a new 
Window (Scene) at the position where I drop the Tab. On OS-X the onMouseReleased gets called, but not on Windows. Can anyone tell me, what the problem is? I'm using JDK 10.0.2

```
public class DragAndDropTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Tab tab = new Tab();
        tab.setGraphic(new Label("Drag me"));

        tab.getGraphic().setOnDragDetected(e -> {
            System.out.println("Drag detected");
            SnapshotParameters param = new SnapshotParameters();
            param.setTransform(Transform.scale(2, 2));
            WritableImage image = tab.getGraphic().snapshot(param, null);
            Dragboard dragboard = tab.getGraphic().startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
            dragboard.setDragView(image);
            ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
            clipboardContent.putString("");
            dragboard.setContent(clipboardContent);
        });

        tab.getGraphic().setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            System.out.println("Mouse Released");
        });

        TabPane tabpane = new TabPane();
        tabpane.getTabs().add(tab);

        StackPane stackpane = new StackPane();
        stackpane.getChildren().add(tabpane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackpane, 500, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Drag to OS Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Look at https://github.com/eclipse/efxclipse-rt/blob/master/modules/ui/org.eclipse.fx.ui.controls/src/main/java/org/eclipse/fx/ui/controls/tabpane/skin/DnDTabPaneSkinHookerFullDrag.java - the missing thing i think is that you start a fullDrag - see https://github.com/eclipse/efxclipse-rt/blob/0f42b816b07bb82015ee8d2d344c905c294ff35c/modules/ui/org.eclipse.fx.ui.controls/src/main/java/org/eclipse/fx/ui/controls/tabpane/skin/DnDTabPaneSkinHookerFullDrag.java#L175

Oh and if you do a fullDrag you don't need to push anything into the clipboard!